# MPMoviePlayerController Overlay iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

Having an issue with MPMoviePLayerController with an overlay in iOS6, prior to iOS6 things were working fine.

It seems I can play a movie in full screen, before I had this code:

```
@interface MovieOverlayViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *skiparrow;
}
@end


@implementation MovieOverlayViewController

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    touchtoskip.frame = CGRectMake( xAdjust,
                                   yAdjust,
                                   touchtoskip.image.size.width / scale, 
                                   touchtoskip.image.size.height / scale);



    [self.view addSubview:touchtoskip];
}
```

Then:

```
overlay = [[MovieOverlayViewController alloc] init];

UIWindow *keyWnd = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[keyWnd addSubview:overlay.view];
```

On my MoviePlayerViewController the view DOES appear. And adds the UIViews, but I see NOTHING anymore.

Really stuck, any suggestions?

Comment: why is this closed? i have exactly the same problem, and found the question very helpful

Comment: i was doing this
UIWindow *keyWnd = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[keyWnd addSubview:overlay.view];
in moviePlayBackDidEnterFullScreen, but it seemed nothing could be added on top of the fullscreen player (in ios6 - worked fine before that). turns out waiting for a small delay before adding the overlays works. not a good solution, but at least shows that the problem is that moviePlayBackDidEnterFullScreen is now too soon to add overlay views.

Comment: Closed because it's too localized? Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that you are getting the key window and adding a subview to that, rather than getting the window's view and adding a subview to that.

Have a look at the [MoviePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample, which shows how to add a player with subviews to control playback.