# iOS 6.0 MPMoviePlayerController full screen mode black color? then App blocked no more actions

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

MPMoviePlayerController video goes to full screen mode at the time screen is black color. And then the app was blocked. This issue only for iOS 6.0. But iOS 5.1 working fine. This is my code. IF I double click the player full screen is opened, But show black screen.

```
 self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:_moviePlayerContentView.bounds]; 
[self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[self.moviePlayerController setAllowsAirPlay:NO];
[_moviePlayerContentView addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
[self.moviePlayerController stop];
[self.moviePlayerController setContentURL:videoURL];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setHidden:NO];
[self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```

How can I handle this issue?

After reach MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded, then How to disable the full screen mode?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code first...

Comment: You can use MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController.... It is working in iOS 6.0 and also in iOS 5.1

Comment: check out this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499312/streaming-video-over-http-in-ios

Comment: Thank you. After reach MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded, then how to disable full screen. Because If full screen mode activate at the time MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded error occurred. Any idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In iOS 6,MPMoviePlayerController full screen calls ViewDidDisappear method. You may have stop player in ViewDidDisappear method. If so, remove it for while and try once again.

Comment: After reach MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded error. How can I remove full screen and show ordinary view. Please explain me.

Comment: these might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725941/ios-6-issue-with-mpmovieplayercontroller
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686972/mpmovieplayercontroller-overlay-ios-6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909834/mpmovieplayercontroller-dismissing-full-screen-mode-not-working-in-ios-6

Comment: Thank you spaleja. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909834/mpmovieplayercontroller-dismissing-full-screen-mode-not-working-in-ios-6 is helpful for me.