# MPMoviePlayerController on iPhone when enter full screen go in pause

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have add `MPMoviePlayerController` in my project in this way:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[player setContentURL:videoURL];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

then when i press a button i play the video:

```
[player play];
```

all works perfect, but when i press the button to enter in the fullscreen mode the video go in pause and i have to press the play button to continue the playback, anyone know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 6.0 MPMoviePlayerController full screen mode black color? then App blocked no more actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437511/ios-6-0-mpmovieplayercontroller-full-screen-mode-black-color-then-app-blocked-n)

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (!self.moviePlayer.isFullscreen) {
        [self.moviePlayer pause];
    }

}
```