# MPMoviePlayer in full screen iniOS6 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

MPMoviePlayer playback time is getting : "nan" when press full screen in iOS-6.
and display fully black screen.
But here in iOS-6 its will working properly in normal mode(not full screen mode).
and in iOS-7 working properly.

Please can you know me how to solve this.

Comment: Check below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437511/ios-6-0-mpmovieplayercontroller-full-screen-mode-black-color-then-app-blocked-n/14437932#14437932

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6,MPMoviePlayerController full screen calls ViewDidDisappear method. You may have stop player in ViewDidDisappear method. If so, remove it for while and try once again.

with iOS 6, apple has made some undocumented changes to MPMoviePLayerController class, when you tap on full screen button, the viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisAppear gets called for both the controller launching MPMoviePLayerController and its ParentController.

In My Project (a pdf reader), I have a very complex view hierarchy, adding a reader in view Controller, then adding the readerPageContents buttons(image Gallery, video, link) to reader page and then playing video on video button tap.So it was calling the ViewWillDisappear and ViewDidDisappear when launching the video in full screen, and when when I press toggle screen button to bring the video to initial frame, the ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear of both controllers called again and I was creating the pdf page again in parent's controller viewDidAppear which was removing the video.

So easier fix it to avoid ViewDidDisappear and ViewWillDisappear gets called by setting some BOOL.